# How do I separate an spf TXT in 2?

Tags: gmail, spf

I have trouble with some SPF records.

```
v=spf1 mx a ptr a: vmh37.fastmag.fr include: fastmag.fr include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Here is my record. It's working well, but there is one kind of mails (@sfr.fr) that does not receive my emails. (it is a GMAIL domain).
The problem seams to be here since 2019 and not solved by SFR (they have many complaints). There is a solution I found (the only one that works apparently) which is to have a record including only gmail:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

would it be ok if I split my TXT spf in 2 different ones like this?

```
v=spf1 mx a ptr a: vmh37.fastmag.fr include: fastmag.fr ~all
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't split them; you can only have one SPF record. Combine them like this:

```
v=spf1 mx a ptr a:vmh37.fastmag.fr include:fastmag.fr include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

I have an SFR account too, and their mail service is horribly slow and unreliable!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Basically I have a g suite account. SFR is blocking all mails from gmail with more than 1 include in the spf. As I need the fastmag inclue (my ERP) it is either I send messages to my SFR customer or I use my ERP :D. I love SFR